# Password Storage Implementation - AES 256 is enough?

Tags: security, encryption, password-protection, aes

I want implement a password storage system, the problem is... i need to store the db (sqlite) somewhere.
So I evaluated to use AES 256, but I'm wandering, in the cloud-computing-era is that enough ? (the algorithm must be 2-way)

Additional question: should I encrypt the entire db or the data inside it ? what is more secure and why ?

Comment: Are these user passwords for e.g. your site, or are you implementing something like a password safe/wallet where you're storing passwords for other sites/applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES-256 is more than enough for anything. AES is both a NIST standard, has been authorized for use in the NSA SuiteB program (http://www.nsa.gov/ia/programs/suiteb_cryptography/), and is generally regarded as the best choice available for block ciphers.

You might want to look at the SQLite encryption extensions. http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html

Encryption is a lot more than just using a cipher. If you roll it yourself, you need to consider the mode of operation (CBC or CTR are the most popular, each one with pros and cons), how you provide integrity (encryption alone doesn't ensure the data hasn't been tampered with), and how you derive the actual key (converting your master password to a cryptographic key).

Comment: Since he says he's implementing a "password storage system" and not an authentication system, I suspect that's the reason why he wants two-way encryption. If you only want to authenticate someone's password, hashing and salting are the way to go. But if, for example, you're writing a program to simplify your life by letting you use a master key instead of a myriad of passwords, then you'll need to recover stored passwords. Hence, symmetrical encryption.

Comment: Ah, I can see your interpretation of "password storage system" as being a "password vault". I agree hashing would be wrong in that case. I read it as an authentication mechanism (perhaps just my own interpretation). In any event, I'd still council against writing any sort of crypto without a firm understanding of how it works. I was a member of the crypto group at NIST, and rarely do such crypto questions lead to good things :). Not reflective of the author in any way, just that it's very hard to do it correctly.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your new information. I can post some more information if you need.

Comment: @mfanto: well, the idea is a keyring for the user. I'm not going to use a vendor-specific solution because i would like to port it to different platforms.

Comment: @Cesar: Do not implement your own cryptography unless you are very careful and think it out after having read the appropriate stuff. And even then consider not doing it. It's very hard to do right. Though AES-256 (if used correctly) is a perfectly safe algorithm, even in the face of massive computing power.

Comment: @mfanto: unfortunatly I'm not a cryptomaster, that's why I'm asking... so i have no idea about "Encryption is a lot more than just using a cipher. What mode of operation will you use? How will you MAC the data? What key derivation functions will you use? " .... what do you suggest ? :)

Comment: @Omnifarious: well in my idea key is generated by server. Distrubuted over SSL behind autentication... then, is AES256 is the right way I'm definitely keen in put effort to implement it properly. I have no deadlines for this project. Anyway, using a component like SQLite encryption extensions do you think could be ok ?

Comment: @Cesar - How about asking a separate question in which you describe the crypto-system you have in mind and letting people offer suggestions or poke holes in it. Your question here is very narrow.

Comment: @Omnifarious this make sense, those questions are outside the scope of the title. Re-posting soon.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is. Even AES 128 would be enough.

Comment: A little reading material too (good read): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/brute-force-key-attacks-are-for-dummies.html